# How to set environment variable using Django and Python?

Tags: python, django

I need to set some environment variable and it should be fetched inside function and the values will go for save inside the database using Django and Python. My code is below:

```
def plantsave(request):
    rname = request.POST.get('react')
    status = request.POST.get('status')
```

Here I am getting the value by post method but instead of it I need to set the value by using `environment variable` and access those values here to submit.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use environ for this case, you should use django session for this type of task
ref [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#examples)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `django session` for that, or just define `global variable`.

Else :

```
import os
# set
os.environ["MY_VAR"] = "1"
# get
MY_VAR = os.environ["MY_VAR"]
```

Comment: Ok,In which file I will set this.same `views.py` file and how i will access it.

Comment: In your function directly

Comment: Can I set like this `rname=os.environ["MY_VAR"]` ?

Comment: To get yes, answer above was to set

Comment: but i have this requiremnt `Smart substitution with environment variables can get around some of these
santization techniques.` and asked to set the vulnerable code.

Comment: That's why you should use django session for that, or just define global variable ... Modify environment varaible is rarely good in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147927/discussion-between-satya-and-glegoux).